# Symmetric NAT - Peer to peer WebRTC

Tags: nat, webrtc

I am currently working on a WebRTC project that aims to communicate people by video conference in peer-to-peer.

However, according to the WebRTC documentation, there may be a problem when a user is behind a symmetrical NAT:

Some routers using NAT use a restriction called'Symmetric NAT'. This means that the router only accepts peer connections to which you have already connected.

In this case, WebRTC uses a TURN server that acts as a proxy to communicate the two people despite the NAT.

Problem: I can't understand what is blocking the system in the operation of a Symmetric NAT? Why is P2P connection not possible on a Symmetric NAT? And on other NATs as well?

If anyone has the answer, I'm interested.

Thank you in advance!!